# Haskell: openFile for multiple handles (W+R+R+R...) w/o "file is locked"

Tags: haskell, locking

I am working on file-backed queue in Haskell (pub/sub + storage).

My idea is to have a log file with W+R+R+R handles to it:

- pub: one W handle, for writing/appending
- sub: multiple R for tailing and random seeking to past entries

However, opening two handles (R+W) to the same file doesn't work with GHC:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-13.0 --install-ghc runghc

module Main where

import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let path = "file.txt"

  _ <- openFile path WriteMode
  _ <- openFile path ReadMode -- throws *** Exception: file.txt: openFile: resource busy (file is locked)
  _ <- openFile path ReadMode
  _ <- openFile path ReadMode

  return ()
```

[File locking](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#g:8) section starts promising:

> Implementations should enforce as far as possible, at least locally to
>   the Haskell process, multiple-reader single-writer locking on files.

... but then says:

> That is, there may either be many handles on the same file which
>   manage input, or just one handle on the file which manages output.

Questions:

- why is there such limitation?
- how to have W+R+R+R handles to a file in Haskell/GHC?

Comment: That's a direct quote from the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/io.html#sect21.2.3). Personally, I disagree with that requirement. I guess it was added to force programmers to write portable code, which would run even on OSs where such locking was mandatory. I don't know of any OS which enforces that today: even windows allows a process to open a file in a shared mode (multiple readers and multiple writers).

Comment: If you don't need to be portable, you could do a work around by hard linking a set of files.

Comment: Maybe an alternative is to go low-level, use `System.Posix.IO` to open the file multiple times, creating FDs, and then turn those into handles. Assuming posix, of course.

Comment: @chi unfortunately calling fdToHandle on first R fd throws the same "locked" exception

Comment: https://gist.github.com/oshyshko/b6728f34903e1458100dda3d095f92ca
- my best attempt so far. It works, but is not pretty, not efficient and uses Fd instead of Handle

Comment: I find it so entertaining that one can't "escape" this limitation even by copying the supposedly locked file, because all copyFiles are read+write. So it looks like C will save the day... again...